# trouble displaying html using django

Tags: html, view, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm following a tutorial to get my hands on django, and I have trouble displaying a kind of 'Hello, world !' :
with url http://127.0.0.1:8000/home, I get :

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/home Using the URLconf defined in
>   mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
>   1.    ^admin/  The current path, home, didn't match any of these.

I don't understand why I get "The current path, home, didn't match any of these.", because :

- List item

urls.py in my project has the following lines :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accueil/', views.home),
]
```

- settings.py includes : ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', ]
- wiews.py of my app défines a view home which returns html (HttpResponse is imported)
- I started the server again :

  python manage.py runserver

Why doesn't 'accueil/' appear in chat is listed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you don't have the part `/home`. The url pointing to your Home view is `accueil/` so you should try http://127.0.0.1:8000/accueli/

Comment: @AmalGuha You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and accept answer if it resolved your issue